# I want a loud or annoying notification of unsent drafts in Gmail

Tags: gmail

From time to time, I forget to send an email. Sure, I can just look at the number of drafts. But what I'd really like would be a hard-to-miss alert whenever I am about to close my Gmail that there are still drafts to be sent.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail doesn't have this feature yet.

If you didn't send a feature request yet to the Gmail engineering team, click on the gear button > Send feedback or post a "question" to the official [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail).

**References:**

[Gmail Help](http://suppport.google.com/mail)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
Editing the **Draft** label to UPPER case letters, `background` and `text` color that stand out, and change settings to only `show when unread`, so the label will only show when there are drafts, making your eye less used to it, thereby more noticeable.
Also, make it a routine to open drafts in a new tab as soon as saving them, so when you are signing out, you'll probably see them.